# cmake error when configuring

Tags: cmake, librocket

Sorry if this is not the right place to post this but I think the librocket forum is long dead.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I followed the steps in building librocket [here](http://librocket.com/wiki/documentation/BuildingWithCMake).

I'm using cmake as the steps said but when I pressed c to configure this error showed up:

```
 CMake Error at
 /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91
 (MESSAGE):
   Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252
 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
   /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:83
 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
   CMakeLists.txt:61 (find_package)
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That means that CMake is trying to automatically find the library Freetype on your disk but does not find it. You will have to tell manually to cmake where is the .so file corresponding to `FREETYPE_LIBRARY` and where is the include directory for `FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

Let's say this library is in the directory `/foo/bar/freetype`, you will have to invoke cmake like you did but with the following options:

```
-DFREETYPE_LIBRARY=/foo/bar/freetype/freetype.so -DFREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS=/foo/bar/freetype/include
```

And if you don't have the library Freetype on your computer, you will - of course - have to download it beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it the next day.