# Is there a Maven equivilent for resolving 3rd party dependencies for Cmake on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, maven, cmake

I am trying to get an environment set up to work with Open Scene Graph (OSG) but I am having a problem with its 3rd party libraries. It is built using cmake but when I run it I get multiple errors like the following:

```
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
```

Threads like the following say its either because the libraries are not installed or cmake just can't find them.

[cmake error when configuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898213/cmake-error-when-configuring)

This would be fine if it was only one lib missing but I'm having problems with 14 libraries. I'm trying to use apt-get and then enter the lib directories in the .profile file so cmake can find them. This seems like it will take all day to get right. I'm new to C, C++ and Linux (just set up my first Ubuntu environment). In Java I could use something like Maven to fix this. Is there anything similiar I could use in this situation?

I've pulled the source from github  and I'm following their instructions to build. https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph.

Complete output:

```
$ cmake .

Could NOT find EGL (missing:  EGL_LIBRARY EGL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find Freetype (missing:  FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR JPEG_LIBRARIES) 
Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing:  LIBXML2_LIBRARIES LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find GDAL (missing:  GDAL_LIBRARY GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find CURL (missing:  CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find GStreamer (missing:  GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES GSTREAMER_VERSION GSTREAMER_BASE_INCLUDE_DIRS GSTREAMER_BASE_LIBRARIES GSTREAMER_APP_INCLUDE_DIRS GSTREAMER_APP_LIBRARIES GSTREAMER_PBUTILS_INCLUDE_DIRS GSTREAMER_PBUTILS_LIBRARIES) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find SDL2 (missing:  SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find SDL (missing:  SDL_LIBRARY SDL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
g++ version 5.4.0 
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
Configuring done
Generating done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would apt-get install openscenegraph. Is there a reason you cannot do this?

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openscenegraph Is the name of the package under debian. Depending upon the distribution you are using the requirements listed on this page are likely to be similar if not identical (see also these: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libopenscenegraph-dev)

Note that openthreads is likely provided by the openscenegraph you are trying to compile

Comment: Seems to have done the trick. Baffled this isn't mentioned in their getting started guide. Maybe just a case of it being so obvious that they assume everyone just knows how to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Paddy Best thing to do is to search the repository for your distribution and see if its already in there. I tend to find that only the obscure ones aren't.