# Do I have FREETYPE_LIBRARY installed?

Tags: cmake, fedora, freetype

I ran a `cmake` command and got the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:156 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (find_package)
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898213/cmake-error-when-configuring) says that I need to specify the .so file corresponding to FREETYPE_LIBRARY and the path to FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS.

My question is how do I know if I have FREETYPE_LIBRARY installed and how to get these paths ?

My OS is Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight).

Comment: I downloaded a rpm file from https://fedora.pkgs.org/28/fedora-x86_64/freetype-2.8-10.fc28.x86_64.rpm.html and ran `sudo dnf install <rpm_file>`; it turned out that freetype package is already installed on my machine; but I still don't know how to get the paths for the cmake flags `FREETYPE_LIBRARY` and `FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS`

Comment: The package you have neither contains the headers files nor the library files without so-version. As usual in programming, you need the **developer** package for program with it. Such packages usually have `-dev` or `-devel` suffixes in their names. This is what you need: https://fedora.pkgs.org/28/fedora-x86_64/freetype-devel-2.8-10.fc28.x86_64.rpm.html.

Comment: It fixed my problem!